# Error al guardar en firebase, no guarda los datos donde se le indica si no que en orden abecedario

Tags: android-studio, firebase, kotlin, gradle, real-time

Estoy trabajando en una APP en android usando Kotlin y firebase Realtime.
anteriormente guardaba normal como se lo indicaba con una data class, pero solo genere el sha-1 release y actualice el gardle y me da este error. al guardar

este es el codigo de guardar en unas de las actividades.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var authFB:FirebaseAuth
    var aStateListener:FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener?=null
    private lateinit var dbRefe: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var database: FirebaseDatabase

    var usu: FirebaseUser?=null
    private lateinit var t1: EditText
    private lateinit var t2:EditText
    private lateinit var btn: Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        authFB=FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        t1=findViewById(R.id.txt1)
        t2=findViewById(R.id.txt2)
        btn=findViewById(R.id.btnEnviar)
        btn.setOnClickListener { save() }

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        authFB=FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        dbRefe = database.reference.child("MCVE/")

    }
    private fun save() {
        val n1:String=t1.text.toString()
        val n2:String=t2.text.toString()
        var usu= authFB?.currentUser?.displayName
        var key=dbRefe.push().key

        val regisUsu = guardar1(nombre = n1, apellido = n2, user = usu.toString(),idUsu = key.toString())

        dbRefe = database.reference.child("MCVE/Cliente")
        dbRefe.child(key.toString()).setValue(regisUsu).addOnCompleteListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "exito", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        //authFB!!.addAuthStateListener { aStateListener!! }
        Toast.makeText(this,authFB?.currentUser?.displayName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
    data class guardar1(var nombre:String?="",var apellido:String?="",var user:String?="",  var idUsu:String?="")
}
```

este es mi gradle a nivel de modulo

no se que tengo mal, como anteriormente les comente guardaba muy bien.
mi version de gradle  es la 5.4.1 y android studio es 3.5.2.

[image: este es mi archivo gradle de nivel modulo]

[image: base de datos]

Comment: El problema es que al compilar la app se esta ofuscando el codigo y los nombres de las clases, propiedades y variables son cambiadas por letras o conjuntos de letras, por eso luego firebase sube los datos pero con los key mal puestos. Sube el contenido de tu archivo ProGuard para que te pueda ayudar a corregirlo

Comment: @ErickSilva que archivo de Proguard estos son los que encontré: proguard-android.txt-3.5.3, proguard-android-optimize.txt-3.5.3 y proguard-defaults.txt-3.5.3. cual tengo que modificar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es correcto lo que menciona Erick, mi App estaba ofuscada al compilar ya que las reglas ProGuard le permitían a R8 quitar mi código y guardar en firebase de distinta forma.
Yo solucione conservando mis funciones y clase de datos que guarda en firebase poniendo una anotación **@Keep** esta permite  mantener toda la clase, función o método tal como esté codificado.

referencia.
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code?hl=es#enable

espero les funcione